# Update method laravel using modal box

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-5.1

My update method is working unfortunately it always updates the wrong data in this case it always updates the last data in my db list. I believe this occurs because my modal box directs to $user->id which always points to the last id as I have a for loop used at the top, is there a ways I could do to point it to the selected id instead?

view.blade.php

```
<div class="well col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    <div class="row user-row">
    <!--div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
        <img class="img-circle"
             src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=50"
             alt="User Pic">
         </div-->
         <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <h5 style="font-weight: bold">{{ $user->name }}</h5>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 dropdown-user" data-for=".{{ $user->id }}">
          <h5 class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down text-muted pull-right">&nbsp;</h5>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row user-infos {{ $user->id }}">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
         <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h2 class="panel-title">User Information</h2>
           </div>
           <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-md-10 col-lg-10 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                   <div class="col-xs-5">User level:</div><div class="col-xs-5"> {{ $user->role->role_description }}</div>
                   <div class="col-xs-5">Email:</div> <div class="col-xs-5"> {{ $user->email }}</div>
                   <div class="col-xs-5">Phone number: </div> <div class="col-xs-5"> {{ $user->mobile }} </div>
                   <div class="col-xs-5">Office extension: </div> <div class="col-xs-5"> [ TO IMPLEMENT ]</div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="panel-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="button"
          data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form">Edit&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
          <span class="pull-right">
             <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button">Inactive&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
         </span>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div> 
@endforeach             
</div> 

@if(Session::has('flash_message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
        {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
    </div>
@endif

<div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2">

    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form">Register New User</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="form" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">User Information</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/manage_accounts/{{ $user->id }}" novalidate>
                   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name">Username:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 @if ($errors->has('name')) has-error @endif"> 
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" type="hidden" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter username">
                       @if ($errors->has('name')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p> @endif
                   </div>
               </div>

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I got my update method to work.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/manage_accounts/" novalidate>
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('.btn--edit').on('click', function(e) {
    var userId = $(this).attr('data-for');
    var formAction = "/manage_accounts/" + userId;

    $('.form-horizontal').attr('action', formAction);
  });
</script>
```

The modal button with class name of .btn--edit,

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btn--edit" type="button" 
          data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update" data-for="{{$user->id}}">Edit&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your modal is referencing the $user object, but it is outside of your foreach loop.

Specifically this line:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/manage_accounts/{{ $user->id }}" novalidate>
```

You could register an onClick event for the modal pop-up button, that grabs a hidden input field of an user's id and dynamically updating the the action URL. Alternatively, you could just have the action URL be the same and handle the logic server side. This approach would have a hidden input field for the user ID that you would be updating, but is a lot cleaner that dealing with URL structure.

Edit:

Javascript Example:

```
<script type="text-javascript">
                    $(function() {
                      $('.btn--edit').on('click', function() {
                        var formAction = $('.form-horizontal').attr('action').replace(/(?!.*/).*, '');
                        var userId = $(this).closest('[name=user_id]').val();
                        $('.form-horizontal').attr('action', formAction + '/' + userId);
                      });
                    });
                    </script>
```

This requires you to update your modal button with a class name of .btn--edit

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btn--edit" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form">Edit&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
```

This also requires you add a hidden input within the foreach somewhere. I chose after the user-infos class.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}" />
```

Comment: Yes, I know what the issue is but  I'm actually quite new in this. Sorry, but would you be kind enough to show a rough solution on how to do it please?

Comment: Updated original comment.